# Java Sql exception but already applied mysql-connector in libraries

Tags: java, mysql, database, sqlexception, connector

I am a beginner in java and am trying to connect it with a database I am having this problem java.sql.SQLException

This is my code

```
import java.sql.*;

public class Driver {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {
        //1. Get a connection to database
        Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection myConn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc.mysql://localhost:3306/demo", "root"," ");

        //2.Create a statement

        Statement myStat = myConn.createStatement();
        //3.Execute SQL query

        ResultSet myRs = myStat.executeQuery("select * from employees");
        //4.Process the result set

        while(myRs.next())
        {
            System.out.println(myRs.getString("last_name")+ ","+myRs.getString("first_name"));
        }

    }catch (Exception exc) {
        exc.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

}
and this is the error

```
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for 
jdbc.mysql://localhost:3306/demo
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
at jdbcdemo.Driver.main(Driver.java:12)
```

I had already applied the mysql-connector-java version.jar in the library but it's not working .can someone help me?

Comment: You have a typo, the JDBC URL prefix for MySQL is `jdbc:mysql:`, not `jdbc.mysql:` (that is **`:`**, not **`.`**).

Answer (score -1):

You are getting **No suitable driver found** error because MySQL-connector is not properly added as a dependency.
If you are using Eclipse as an IDE try to add external library from project build path.
An alternative way is clean-refresh your project and verifies dependencies are defined in the classpath or not.

Comment: I already tried this it does not work

Answer (score -1):

**1**

Add the jar file into WEB-INF/lib/ folder

**2**

Right click on the project folder
Select Build path
Select Configure build path
Select Libraries
Select Add external JARS
Add the jar

**3**

```
DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc.mysql://localhost:3306/demo", "root"," ")
```

In this statement replace "demo" with a existing database name which you created and make sure your mysql server is up and running